# Erro SublimeText

Tags: php, sublime-text

Alguém já teve este erro ao iniciar o Sublime Text:

> Error loading syntax file "Packages/PHP/PHP.sublime-syntax": Apparent
>   recursion within a with_prototype action: 25000 context sanity limit
>   hit

Comment: Isso foi algum pacote que instalou/corrompeu. Procure sobre gerenciar pacotes no sublime.

Comment: Já tive o mesmo erro, depois de desabilitar o pacote de CSS3 ele voltou a funcionar

Comment: Certo obrigado! Acabei reinstalando, mas antes tirei o diretório: C:\Users\Meu_Usuario\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3

Answer (score 0):

Em pleno 2021 e este erro ainda persiste. Na verdade agora o problema está acontecendo também com o pacote Java​Script​Next - ES6 Syntax ( https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JavaScriptNext%20-%20ES6%20Syntax )

A solução é desabilitar CSS3 e Java​Script​Next - ES6 Syntax.

Eu desisti do Sublime Text por conta deste bug com o JavaScriptNext - ES6 Syntax, pois gostava do efeito no javascript / jquery.